# How can I execute a shell-script in a Bash sub-shell?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a shell-function that executes a command within a sub-shell, after setting some environment variables, e.g.

```
$ with-env-overrides git status
```

It's implemented using `eval` in a sub-shell

```
with-env-overrides() {
  (
    source $HOME/.env-overrides
    eval "$@"
  )
}
```

this means I can make use of aliases, and shell-functions, e.g.

```
$ with-env-overrides gs
```

but unfortunately, eval gets confused when arguments contain spaces, or shell meta-characters, e.g.

```
$ with-env-overrides grep "foo bar" /etc/passwd
grep: bar: No such file or directory
```

How can I achieve this without using `eval`, but without loosing the ability to use aliases etc?

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same but *without* eval.

```
with-env-overrides() {
  (
    source $HOME/.env-overrides
    "$@"
  )
}
```

Example:

```
$ cat ~/.env-overrides 
export A=1000
$ export | grep ^A=
$ with-env-overrides export | ^grep A=
declare -x A="1000"
```

As you can see, in the second case, you've got an environment with the `A` variable.

Comment: Exactly what I would suggest.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately, I don't appear to be able to leverage aliases using that method.

Comment: @MikeWilliams: That's correct. Aliases are very limited, and have a number of wierdnesses. One of them is that they act more like built-ins than commands, so you cannot quote them or construct them out of two strings, or expand a parameter to invoke one. Use shell functions instead.